# How to use safe raw queries against sql injections in laravel4 for INSERT IGNORE

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

My laravel 4 query is like below:

```
foreach (Input::get('classrooms') as $keyc=>$valuec) {
        foreach (Input::get('subject') as $keys=>$values) {
        $valuesArray[] = "('".$valuec."','".$values."')"; 
            }
        }
        $someVariable = implode(",",$valuesArray);
        DB::select( DB::raw("INSERT IGNORE INTO classrooms_subjects (`classroom_id`,`subject_id`) VALUES $someVariable"));
```

I am really concerned if thats the safest way and any solution for this..

I have done some research and found a way but not sure if its safe:
please let me know if below code is safe:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO classrooms_subjects (".implode(",", $columns).") ";
        $sql .= " SELECT ".implode(",", $columns)." FROM classrooms_subjects WHERE id IN (".$toCopy.")";
        DB::insert($sql);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Just to ask, why do you use raw SQL instead of the eloquent model?

Comment: just dont know how to do INSERT IGNORE  through eloquent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to bind some data then try like this (according to the docs):

```
DB::insert(
    'INSERT IGNORE INTO classrooms_subjects (`classroom_id`,`subject_id`) VALUES (?, ?)',
     [$classroomId, $subjectId]
);
```

You can pass data with array as a secound parameter here.